# None-admin-users can't connect to facebook-app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

we have been operating a facebook-app which allows the user to publish content to facebook-pages after connecting to the app. Recently a user notified us about an issue. When the user tries to connect to the app, he receives a notification that the app is currently not available and that he should contact the app-developer for further help. After looking at the app-settings we have not been able to find an issue with it. As an admin I can still connect the app through my facebook-account but for users who don't have an admin-role a connection can not be established. Does anybody have experienced the same error or does anybody know why this error occurs? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: According to the app-settings the app should be visible to the public. There should not be any issue on that side of things.